Uploading Files to S3 Bucket usign Deno module deno-s3-lite-client
I have been trying to make a file upload controller with deno's s3 lite client but I am facing an issue with uploading the content type of my file. In their documentation, i can read that the way to use the putObject() fucntion is like this:
Deno.test({
name: "putObject() can stream a large file upload",
fn: async () =\> {
// First generate a 32MiB file in memory, 1 MiB at a time, as a stream
const dataStream = ReadableStream.from(async function\* () {
for (let i = 0; i \< 32; i++) {
yield new Uint8Array(1024 \* 1024).fill(i % 256); // Yield 1MB of data
}
}());

    // Upload the 32MB stream data as 7 5MB parts. The client doesn't know in advance how big the stream is.
    const key = "test-32m.dat";
    const metadata = { "Content-Type": "test/streaming", "x-amz-meta-custom-header": "This is a custom value!" };
    const response = await client.putObject(key, dataStream, { partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, metadata });
    // The etag is generated by the server, based on the contents. Also, etags for multi-part uploads are
    // different than for regular uploads, so the "-7" confirms it worked and used a multi-part upload.
    assertEquals(response.etag, "ca6d977b6e7dc87ab5c5892e124c7277-7");
    // Validate that the metadata was set:
    const stat = await client.statObject(key);
    assertEquals(stat.metadata, metadata);

},
});

And in my code I have it like this:

export async function uploadFileToS3(
companyId: string,
categoryId: string,
dppId: string | null,
fileData: File,
fileName: string,
fileType: string, 
): Promise\<string\> {
if (!fileData) {
throw new Error("File data is undefined or null");
}
console.log("Uploading file to S3:", fileData.type); // Debugging line

    try {
        // Read the file as an ArrayBuffer
        const buffer = await fileData.arrayBuffer();
        // Convert ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array
        const fileArrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    
        let filePath = "";
    
        if (fileType === "categoryImage") {
            filePath = `companies/${companyId}/categories/${categoryId}/category-image/${fileName}`;
        } else if (fileType === "dppFile") {
            filePath = `companies/${companyId}/categories/${categoryId}/dpps/${dppId}/${fileName}`;
        } else if (fileType === "modelFile") {
            filePath = `companies/${companyId}/categories/${categoryId}/models/${fileName}`;
        }
    
        // Debugging log for filePath
        console.log("Uploading file to S3 with filePath:", filePath);
    
        // Use contentType option to set the Content-Type header directly
        const metadata = {
            "Content-Type": fileData.type,
        };
        // Upload the file using the S3 client
        await s3Client.putObject(filePath, fileArrayBuffer, { metadata});
        console.log("Upload successful");
    
        // Verify the uploaded file's metadata
        const stat = await s3Client.statObject(filePath);
        console.log("Uploaded file metadata:", stat.metadata);
    
        return filePath;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading to S3:", error);
        throw error;
    }

}

Can you tell where the problem is from here? I get the file uploaded succesfully but the type of it in the s3 bucket is empty and I cannot open it since it got this problem.
I have tried combining the content type in multiple ways and none of them work.
